# Dependent type as a function argument in Coq

Tags: function, coq, dependent-type

I am very new to Coq. I am trying to experiment with Coq's dependent types. What I want to do, is to simply feed an even number to a function. For example, in pseudo-code:

```
def next_even(n: {n: Integer | n is even}) :=
{
  add n 2
}
```

Then I want to utilize the function with different arguments, such as (in pseudo-code):

```
next_even(1)    // Coq should show an error
next_even(4)    // Coq should compute 6
```

So, in Coq, I want to do the following:

```
Compute (next_even 1).
Compute (next_even 4).
```

How can I construct it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a direct translation of your function in Coq:

```
From Coq Require Import Arith.

Definition add_two_even (n : {n : nat | Nat.even n = true}) : nat :=
  proj1_sig n + 1.
```

Note that you need the `proj1_sig` function to extract `n` from the subset type `{n : nat | Nat.even n = true}`. To use `add_two_even`, you also need to go the other way around: go from a number to an element of `{n | Nat.even n = true}`. In Coq, this requires manual proof. For concrete values of `n`, this is easy:

```
(* The next command fails with a type checking error *)
Fail Compute add_two_even (exist _ 1 eq_refl).
(* The next command succeeds *)
Compute add_two_even (exist _ 4 eq_refl).
```

The `exist` constructor wraps a value `x` with a proof of `P x`, producing an element of the subset type `{x | P x}`. The `eq_refl` term is a proof of `x = x` for any value of `x`.  When `n` is a concrete number, Coq can evaluate `Nat.even n` and find if `eq_refl` is a valid proof of `Nat.even n = true`. When `n` is `1`, `Nat.even n = false`, and the check fails, leading to the first error message. When `n` is `4`, the check succeeds.

Things get more complicated when `n` is not a constant, but an arbitrary expression.  A proof that `Nat.even n = true` can require detailed reasoning that must be guided by the user.  For instance, we know that `Nat.even (n + n) = true` for any value of `n`, but Coq does not. Thus, to call `add_two_even` on something of the form `n + n`, we need to show a lemma.

```
Lemma add_n_n_even n : Nat.even (n + n) = true.
Proof.
induction n as [|n IH]; trivial.
now simpl; rewrite <- plus_n_Sm, IH.
Qed.

Definition foo (n : nat) :=
  add_two_even (exist _ (n + n) (add_n_n_even n)).
```

There are some tools for facilitating this style of programming, such as the [equations plugin](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations), but the general wisdom in the Coq community is that you should avoid subset types for functions like `add_two_even`, where the constraints do not substantially simplify the properties about the function.

You can find many examples of good uses of subset types in the [Mathematical Components](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp) libraries.  For example, the libraries use subset types to define a type `n.-tuple T` of lists of length `n`, and a type `'I_n` of integers bounded by `n`.  This allows us to define a total accessor function `tnth (t : n.-tuple T) (i : 'I_n) : T` that extracts the `i`th element of the list `t`.  If we define this accessor for arbitrary lists and integers, we need to pass a default value to the function to return when the index is out of bounds, or change the function's signature so that it returns a value of type `option T` instead, indicating that the function can fail to return a value.  This change makes properties of the accessor function harder to state.  For example, consider the `eq_from_tnth` lemma, which says that two lists are equal if all their elements are equal:

```
eq_from_tnth:
  forall (n : nat) (T : Type) (t1 t2 : n.-tuple T),
    (forall i : 'I_n, tnth t1 i = tnth t2 i) -> t1 = t2
```

The statement of this lemma for arbitrary lists becomes more complicated, because we need an extra assumption saying that the two lists are of the same size. (Here, `x0` is the default value.)

```
eq_from_nth:
  forall (T : Type) (x0 : T) (s1 s2 : list T),
  size s1 = size s2 ->
  (forall i : nat, i < size s1 -> nth x0 s1 i = nth x0 s2 i) -> s1 = s2
```

Comment: What do you mean the general wisdom is not to use subset types? What should you use then? I think subset types are used in mathcomp and for good reasons, they are easier to manipulate than indexed-inductive types.

Comment: Yes, the mathcomp libraries provide a good pattern of use for subset types. What I meant is that it is generally a bad idea to use a subset type for a function like `add_two_even`, where the added constraints on the signature would probably not simplify the properties about this function. I'll try to explain it better in my answer.